# Matlab to Julia Optimization: Function in JuMP @SetNLObjective

Tags: matlab, julia, mathematical-optimization, julia-jump

I am trying to rewrite a Matlab fmincon optimization function in Julia.

Here is the Matlab code:

```
function [x,fval] = example3()

  x0 = [0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0];  
  A = [];                         
  b = [];
  Ae = [1000 1000 1000 1000 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000];   
  be = [100];                     
  lb = [0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0];  
  ub = [1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1];  
  noncon = [];                  

  options = optimset('fmincon');
  options.Algorithm = 'interior-point';

  [x,fval] = fmincon(@objfcn,x0,A,b,Ae,be,lb,ub,@noncon,options);

end

function f = objfcn(x) 

  % user inputs
  Cr = [ 0.0064 0.00408 0.00192 0; 
       0.00408 0.0289 0.0204 0.0119;
       0.00192 0.0204 0.0576 0.0336; 
       0 0.0119 0.0336 0.1225 ];

  w0 = [ 0.3; 0.3; 0.2; 0.1 ];
  Er = [0.05; 0.1; 0.12; 0.18];

  % calculate objective function
  w = w0+x(1:4)-x(5:8);
  Er_p = w'*Er;
  Sr_p = sqrt(w'*Cr*w);

  % f = objective function
  f = -Er_p/Sr_p;

end
```

and here is my Julia code:

```
using JuMP
using Ipopt

m = Model(solver=IpoptSolver())

# INPUT DATA
w0 = [ 0.3; 0.3; 0.2; 0.1 ]
Er = [0.05; 0.1; 0.12; 0.18]
Cr = [ 0.0064 0.00408 0.00192 0; 
    0.00408 0.0289 0.0204 0.0119;
    0.00192 0.0204 0.0576 0.0336; 
    0 0.0119 0.0336 0.1225 ]

# VARIABLES
@defVar(m, 0 <= x[i=1:8] <= 1, start = 0.0)
@defNLExpr(w, w0+x[1:4]-x[5:8])
@defNLExpr(Er_p, w'*Er)
@defNLExpr(Sr_p, w'*Cr*w)
@defNLExpr(f, Er_p/Sr_p)

# OBJECTIVE
@setNLObjective(m, Min, f)

# CONSTRAINTS 
@addConstraint(m, 1000*x[1] + 1000*x[2] + 1000*x[3] + 1000*x[4] - 
1000*x[5] - 1000*x[6] - 1000*x[7] - 1000*x[8] == 100)

# SOLVE
status = solve(m)

# DISPLAY RESULTS
println("x = ", round(getValue(x),4))
println("f = ", round(getObjectiveValue(m),4))
```

Julia optimization works when I explicitly define the objective function in @setNLObjective however this is unsuitable as the user's input can change resulting in a different objective function, which you can see from how the objective function is created.

The issue seems to be JuMP's limitation in how the objective function can be entered in the @setNLObjective argument:

> All expressions must be simple scalar operations. You cannot use dot, matrix-vector products, vector slices, etc. Translate vector operations into explicit sum{} operations.

Is there a way around this? 
Or are there any other packages in Julia which solve this, bearing in mind I will not have the jacobian or hessian.

Many thanks.

Comment: The package `NLopt` does not have this limitation. You can pass in any function or anonymous function.

Comment: I've had a look at NLopt and looks to be what I am after but the lack of examples is stopping my progress. Could you possibly give me a simple example using NLopt? or even my function in NLopt. Thanks

Comment: I asked a question about `NLopt` here on SO about a week ago that included a working example of a simple problem. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755612/unexpected-behaviour-of-ftol-abs-and-ftol-rel-in-nlopt) is the link. Make sure you've got that working on your machine, then if you're still having problems, get back to me here and I'll see if I can provide more help.

Comment: I managed to get it working using your example and it should help me finish the project with NLopt. I ran into a small problem where the objective function was created from matrix multiplication and passing it to min_objective! was giving me an error. I fixed this by creating a variable whose value was the 1st element of the 1x1 matrix and passed this to the objective function. I will post my code as an answer down below. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Working example of the Matlab code using Julia and NLopt optimization package.

```
using NLopt

function objective_function(x::Vector{Float64}, grad::Vector{Float64})

    w0 = [ 0.3; 0.3; 0.2; 0.1 ]
    Er = [0.05; 0.1; 0.12; 0.18]
    Cr = [ 0.0064 0.00408 0.00192 0; 
            0.00408 0.0289 0.0204 0.0119;
            0.00192 0.0204 0.0576 0.0336; 
            0 0.0119 0.0336 0.1225 ]

    w = w0 + x[1:4] - x[5:8]

    Er_p = w' * Er

    Sr_p = sqrt(w' * Cr * w)

    f = -Er_p/Sr_p

    obj_func_value = f[1]

    return(obj_func_value)
end

function constraint_function(x::Vector, grad::Vector)

    constraintValue = 1000*x[1] + 1000*x[2] + 1000*x[3] + 1000*x[4] -
1000*x[5] - 1000*x[6] - 1000*x[7] - 1000*x[8] - 100        

return constraintValue
end

opt1 = Opt(:LN_COBYLA, 8)

lower_bounds!(opt1, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
upper_bounds!(opt1, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

#ftol_rel!(opt1, 0.5)
#ftol_abs!(opt1, 0.5)

min_objective!(opt1, objective_function)
equality_constraint!(opt1,  constraint_function)

(fObjOpt, xOpt, flag) = optimize(opt1, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```